# Parsing inner hits along with source

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

We are using Jest java client for interacting with E.S in our application.

**We have a document structure like below :**

```
{
  "productId":123,
  "reviews":[ // <============ NESTED
   {"id":1, "rating":3, "epoch":12345}
   {"id":2, "rating":4, "epoch":12346}
  ]
}
```

**Product Class:**

```
 class Product {
    int productId;
    List<Review> reviews; // Review class has id, rating and epoch
  }
```

We have to return the most recent review for each product. For that, we are using **inner_hits** query.

**Help needed for:**
I tried my best but I didn't find any method with-in JEST client to parse inner_hits along with the source.

Comment: which ES version you are using? JEST is not official client and ES provides official client for recent versions.

Comment: E.S version we are using is 5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not yet implement in Jest.

An [issue](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/issues/632) has been opened two years ago, but it is still open today.

It looks like Jest has been "dormant" to say the least...

You should consider leveraging the [official High-Level Java REST client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high.html) instead as it provides support for `inner_hits` as you would expect.

Comment: we are using elastic search 5.5.X. Does the rest high level client 5.6.0 works well with the same ?